# Create JSON tree structure from array of objects with multi-levels

Tags: javascript, json, tree

I have an array of objects in json like this:

```
[{
    "vehicleid": 3,
    "name": "Teste2VDD",
    "brand": "Scania",
    "model": "6x2",
    "class": "class1",
    "region": "Curitiba",
    "customer": "Cliente A",
    "customerid": 1
},
{
    "vehicleid": 1,
    "name": "Teste1",
    "brand": "Volkswagen",
    "model": "5x3",
    "class": "class1",
    "region": "Curitiba",
    "customer": "Cliente A",
    "customerid": 1
},
{
    "vehicleid": 2,
    "name": "Teste3VDD",
    "brand": "Volkswagen",
    "model": "6x2",
    "class": "class2",
    "region": "Curitiba",
    "customer": "Cliente A",
    "customerid": 1
},
{
    "vehicleid": 5,
    "name": "Teste4VDD",
    "brand": "Scania",
    "model": "6x4",
    "class": "class2",
    "region": "Curitiba",
    "customer": "Novo",
    "customerid": 2
},
{
    "vehicleid": 6,
    "name": "Teste5VDD",
    "brand": "Scania",
    "model": "5x5",
    "class": "class2",
    "region": "Curitiba",
    "customer": "Novo",
    "customerid": 2
},
{
    "vehicleid": 7,
    "name": "veiculo",
    "brand": "Scania",
    "model": "5x4",
    "class": "class1",
    "region": "Porto Alegre",
    "customer": "Cliente3",
    "customerid": 3
},
{
    "vehicleid": 8,
    "name": "veiculo65",
    "brand": "Volkswagen",
    "model": "5x4",
    "class": "class3",
    "region": "Porto Alegre",
    "customer": "Cliente3",
    "customerid": 3
},
{
    "vehicleid": 11,
    "name": "Veiculo de teste h",
    "brand": "Scania",
    "model": "5x3",
    "class": "class3",
    "region": "Belo Horizonte",
    "customer": "Cliente de teste h",
    "customerid": 10
},
{
    "vehicleid": 13,
    "name": "Nome 3",
    "brand": "Volkswagen",
    "model": "6x3",
    "class": "class3",
    "region": "Belo Horizonte",
    "customer": "Cliente de teste h",
    "customerid": 10
},
{
    "vehicleid": 12,
    "name": "Nome",
    "brand": "Volvo",
    "model": "6x3",
    "class": "class3",
    "region": "Belo Horizonte",
    "customer": "Cliente de teste h",
    "customerid": 10
}]
```

And I need to create an tree hierarquia depending on which filters I pass as parameter.

The first level will always be the **customer** and the last level will always be the **vehicle**.

For example:

1 - If I select to filter the tree by **Customer**, the tree will be ordered by Customer, then the children of the **Customer** will be the **Vehicles**, like this:

```
[{
    "attr": {
        "type": "customer"
    },
    "text": "Cliente A",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Teste1",
            "attr": {
                "type": "vehicle",
                "title": "Teste1"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Teste3VDD",
            "attr": {
                "type": "vehicle",
                "title": "Teste3VDD"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "text": "Teste2VDD",
            "attr": {
                "type": "vehicle",
                "title": "Teste2VDD"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "attr": {
        "type": "customer"
    },
    "text": "Novo",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "text": "Teste4VDD",
            "attr": {
                "type": "vehicle",
                "title": "Teste4VDD"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "text": "Teste5VDD",
            "attr": {
                "type": "vehicle",
                "title": "Teste5VDD"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "attr": {
        "type": "customer"
    },
    "text": "Cliente3",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "text": "veiculo",
            "attr": {
                "type": "vehicle",
                "title": "veiculo"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "text": "veiculo65",
            "attr": {
                "type": "vehicle",
                "title": "veiculo65"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "attr": {
        "type": "customer"
    },
    "text": "Cliente",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "text": "Veiculo de teste h",
            "attr": {
                "type": "vehicle",
                "title": "Veiculo de teste h"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "text": "Nome",
            "attr": {
                "type": "vehicle",
                "title": "Nome"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "text": "Nome 3",
            "attr": {
                "type": "vehicle",
                "title": "Nome 3"
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

2 - If I select to filter the tree by **Brand**, the tree will be ordered by **Customer**, then the children of the **Customer** will be the **Brand**,  then the children of the **Brand** wil be **Vehicles**

3 - If I select to filter the tree by **Brand** and **Model**, the tree will be ordered by **Customer**, then the children of the **Customer** will be the **Brand**, then the children of the **Brand** will be **Model** then the children of the **Model** will be **Vehicles**

4 - If I select to filter the tree by **Brand**, **Model** and "Region", the tree will be ordered by **Customer**, then the children of the **Customer** will be the **Brand**, then the children of the **Brand** will be **Model** then the children of the **Model** will be **Region**, then the children of the **Region** will be **Vehicles**

And so on...

Anyone knows something to make this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, javascript will do the trick nicely.

Comment: I think you need to do it all manually in a loop. No tools or libraries.

Comment: You need to iterate your data.

Comment: Why the upvote? :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dynamic approach with grouping by given keys or object with group name and key and build a nested structure by using a hash table for each level.

```js
function groupBy(array, keys) {
    var result = [],
        temp = { _: result };

    data.forEach(function (a) {
        keys.reduce(function (r, k, i, kk) {
            var type = typeof k === 'object' ? Object.keys(k)[0] : k,
                key = typeof k === 'object' ? a[k[type]] : a[k];

            if (!r[key]) {
                r[key] = { _: [] };
                r._.push(i + 1 < kk.length
                    ? { attr: { type: type }, text: key, children: r[key]._ }
                    : { id: a.vehicleid, text: key, attr: { type: type, title: key } }
                );
            }
            return r[key];
        }, temp);
    });

    return result;
}

var data = [{ vehicleid: 3, name: "Teste2VDD", brand: "Scania", model: "6x2", class: "class1", region: "Curitiba", customer: "Cliente A", customerid: 1 }, { vehicleid: 1, name: "Teste1", brand: "Volkswagen", model: "5x3", class: "class1", region: "Curitiba", customer: "Cliente A", customerid: 1 }, { vehicleid: 2, name: "Teste3VDD", brand: "Volkswagen", model: "6x2", class: "class2", region: "Curitiba", customer: "Cliente A", customerid: 1 }, { vehicleid: 5, name: "Teste4VDD", brand: "Scania", model: "6x4", class: "class2", region: "Curitiba", customer: "Novo", customerid: 2 }, { vehicleid: 6, name: "Teste5VDD", brand: "Scania", model: "5x5", class: "class2", region: "Curitiba", customer: "Novo", customerid: 2 }, { vehicleid: 7, name: "veiculo", brand: "Scania", model: "5x4", class: "class1", region: "Porto Alegre", customer: "Cliente3", customerid: 3 }, { vehicleid: 8, name: "veiculo65", brand: "Volkswagen", model: "5x4", class: "class3", region: "Porto Alegre", customer: "Cliente3", customerid: 3 }, { vehicleid: 11, name: "Veiculo de teste h", brand: "Scania", model: "5x3", class: "class3", region: "Belo Horizonte", customer: "Cliente de teste h", customerid: 10 }, { vehicleid: 13, name: "Nome 3", brand: "Volkswagen", model: "6x3", class: "class3", region: "Belo Horizonte", customer: "Cliente de teste h", customerid: 10 }, { vehicleid: 12, name: "Nome", brand: "Volvo", model: "6x3", class: "class3", region: "Belo Horizonte", customer: "Cliente de teste h", customerid: 10 }];

console.log(groupBy(data, ['customer', { vehicle: 'name' }]));
console.log(groupBy(data, ['brand', 'customer', { vehicle: 'name' }]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Fantastic Nina, I will work with your reference, thank you very much!

Comment: I did not know the reduce(). It made the code much easier, thank you very much!